# Can check a Array multiple times from different threads

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multithreading

So i want to check a file if it contains a data. My program is multi-threaded so it won't work as the file can't be accessed at same time and also gives error, is it possible to load it up on string Array and check if that array contains the text i want ?

If i check it from 5-10 different threads at exactly same time will it matter ?

and How can I write a text to a file from all these threads at the same time but it should look if it being used and wait and then write so no error is logged.

Answer (score 0):

> ... is it possible to load it up on string Array and check if that array contains the text i want ?

Yes.  It is straight-forward programming to read a file into an array of strings, and to check if one of the strings in the array contains another string.

> If i check it from 5-10 different threads at exactly same time will it matter ?

Yes, it matters.  You have to implement the code the right way to ensure that it always works.

Your question is very hard to decipher, but I am guessing that you want the array of strings to be shared between the threads, AND you want the threads to update the array.  In that case, proper synchronization is essential, or you are liable to run into race conditions and memory anomalies.

> How can I write a text to a file from all these threads at the same time but it should look if it being used and wait and then write so no error is logged.

You need to synchronize properly so that only one thread attempts to write to the file at any one time.  In addition, you need to make sure that one thread doesn't attempt to open a stream to the file while another stream has the file open.  (That is most likely the cause of your current errors.  Java on Windows won't let you do that ... though Java on Linux will allow it.)

---

I suggest you read the Oracle Java Tutorials on how to write multi-threaded programs.

Comment: I am writing it on vb. But thanks, i decided to edit my first codes to give suitable ID to each and maintain separate files of data just for this sake.